# Hiding scrollbars in message field

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a message field to a website. The message field works fine in all browser except IE. There is a vertical scroll bar that keeps displaying next to it. Please help me out to remove it. Thanks

[image]
Here is the code,

```
  <textarea name="message" cols="38" rows="12" id="message" style=" font-family: Verdana; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 13px; background-color: #0E0E0F; border: 1px solid #740086; width:385px;" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" margin-bottom:10px;="margin-bottom:10px;overflow: hidden;">Message</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the CSS.

```
<textarea
    name="message"
    cols="38"
    rows="12"
    id="message"
    style="font-family:Verdana; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:13px; background-color:#0E0E0F; border:1px solid #740086; width:385px;margin-bottom:10px;overflow:hidden;"
    onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
    onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
Message
</textarea>
```

You also had a syntax error in your HTML:

```
this.value=this.defaultValue;" margin-bottom:10px;="margin-bottom:10px;overflow: hidden;">
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTUpt/2/).

Comment: The code I gave has this property in it. It does not work. Checked your code to on IE.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your style:

```
textarea { overflow: auto; }
```

Found it [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-scrollbar-from-textarea-in-ie/)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
textarea { overflow: auto; }
```